# Ransack Sorting Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, ransack

I've been troubleshooting this for a while and have seen a couple issues that seem to describe my problem but none of the solutions work.

I have two models property and listings, I want to add a sort link that will sort a list of properties by a field on the listing.

My models look like:

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :listings
end


class Listing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :property
end
```

Controller does:

```
@q =Property.joins(:listings).select('id', 'full_address', 'price_pence', 'first_listed_date', 'property_type', 'bedrooms', 'listings.agency').ransack(params[:q])
@properties = @q.result
```

So how do I make my sort link work?

```
<%= sort_link(@q, :listing_agency, 'Agency') %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`<%= sort_link(@q, :listings_agency, 'Agency') %>`

Instead of

`<%= sort_link(@q, :listing_agency, 'Agency') %>`

We have to use `#{association}_#{field_name}`

So, in your case user association is `listings` not `listing`